# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException while using org.apache.hadoop DistributedFileSystem

Tags: java, api, hadoop, hdfs, cascading

```
String inputPath = args[0];
FileSystem dfs = new DistributedFileSystem();
FileStatus[] files= null;
try{
     files = dfs.listStatus(new path(inputPath));
}
catch(IOExcpeption err){
    //Do stuff
}
```

The code build fine with maven. However, when I try to run it, I get a nullPointerException inside the try clause. Any ideas?

Comment: I've almost figured it out. I need to initialize dfs using 
    dfs.initialize(new URI, new Configuration)
where URI is a plain java class and Configuration is from hadoop-core in org.apache.hadoop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instantiating a FileSystem class requires a Configuration object in the constructor. One very simply way to do this is with the following:

```
FileSystem lfs = FileSystem.get(new Configuration());
```

Use this when creating the FileSystem object. This also has the added bonus of using the local configuration, so you don't have to change your code when switching between a hadoop and a local file structure.